# How can I pass command line arguments to a standalone MATLAB executable running on Linux/Unix?

Tags: matlab, command-line-arguments, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

How can I pass command line arguments to a standalone MATLAB executable 
running on Linux/UNIX?

I need to compile my MATLAB script as a standalone file that can be run on a machine without MATLAB present. It needs to be able to work in a way similar to C's `argv[]`, where you do the following:

Command line:

```
myfile argument1.txt argument2.txt
```

where argument 1 and 2 are the input and output files.

The exact syntax doesn't matter, but it should work like `argv[]`. What is a function that could do this?

---

What I mean is that I have MATLAB on my computer, but I need to make an standalone executable that can run on Unix systems WITHOUT MATLAB on those computers (it's a cluster, that only has MATLAB on one node). I need to find a way to make the varargin function without having MATLAB installed on the computer that's running the program. If I can tell MATLAB to put the MATLAB library in each executable, that's OK, as long as it's a complete standalone package.

Answer (score 27):

The MATLAB website has a
[worked-through example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/create-and-install-a-standalone-application-from-matlab-code.html) with instructions on how to compile a simple application and how to deploy it on another computer. In essence, you need to install the
MATLAB Compiler Runtime together with your application; the installer
for the runtime should already be present in your MATLAB compiler
installation.

To pass command-line arguments to a MATLAB executable, you define a
single MATLAB function in the executable: the arguments to the
function are taken from the command line parameters (the first command-line parameter is the first argument, and so on).

For example, create a file `echo.m` with the following
contents:

```
function exitcode = echo(a, b)

display(a);
display(b);

exitcode = 0;
```

You can then compile this file and run it with `echo 1 2 3`, and it
will print `a=1 b=2`.

Note that, when arguments are taken from the command line, they are
passed to the function as *strings*, so you need to convert them to
numbers using the `str2num` function. For instance:

```
function rc = display_product(a, b)

a = str2num(a);
b = str2num(b);

display(a*b);

rc = 0;
```

Comment: What about the returned value?

Comment: I tried to follow the link and ended up at a generic mathworks page. In an attempt to find a new, updated url so I could edit the answer with it, I was asked for a mathworks login just to access the documentation. I think Mathworks is subconsciously begging for people to abandon them for octave, R, and numpy.

Comment: @mightypile I have replaced the broken link with a new one; but I do not know, (1) whether this is the same content that I linked to in 2001, and (2) whether a MathWorks account is needed to *view* the page (I concur with your final remark...)

Comment: I have changed this link to one that does not contain a version number. This link should not require a license to view (you only need a license to read documentation for previous versions of MATLAB, hence a link with a version number, if visible now without a license, will no longer be visible when a new version is released).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and searched for a generic solution to the problem that in a script, the arguments are passed as strings, but needed as scalars or vectors. 
Suppose you have the following function

```
function myfunc(arg1, arg2, varargs)
end
```

and you maybe want to be able to call it like

```
myfunc(1, [1 2 3], 'optional1', 2)
```

and also like

```
myfunc('1', '[1 2 3]', 'optional1', '2')
```

so that you can compile it and use it on the command line like

```
myfunc 1 '[1 2 3]' optional1 2
```

For this, I wrote the following function:

```
function r=evalArguments(parser, arguments)
    % Evaluates parsed arguments' values.  
    % Given a parser containing parsed arguments, all string values of the
    % arguments specified by parameter "arguments" are evaluated 
    % and the complete results is returned in a new struct.

    r = parser.Results;
    for j=1:length(arguments)
        argValue = r.(arguments{j});
        if ischar(argValue)
            r.(arguments{j}) = eval(argValue);
        end
    end
end
```

Then I am able to use the [inputParser](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser-class.html) in `myfunc` like this:

```
p = inputParser;
p.addRequired('arg1');
p.addRequired('arg2');
p.addParameter('optional1', 0);
p.parse(arg1, arg2, varargin{:});
nonStringArguments = {'arg1', 'arg2', 'optional1'};
args = evalArguments(p, nonStringArguments);
...
x = args.arg1;
y = args.arg2;
z = args.optional1;
```

As I did not find an out-of-the-box way to do it, I post this solution here and hope it may also be useful to others.
If there is a better way to achieve this, please let me know.

Comment: If `isdeployed` you can expect the input arguments to be strings, otherwise you don’t need to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really run MATLAB on a computer without MATLAB. You can install the MCR (MATLAB Component Runtime), which is free to install, and run MATLAB programs. To build a 'standalone' executable you'll also need the MATLAB compiler.

Once you have all that. MATLAB has all the facilities you need to handle command line arguments in the way your require.