# Matlab compiler executable return argument

Tags: matlab, command-line-arguments, matlab-compiler

Following this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8988568/1357553 , regarding how to pass command line arguments to an EXE generated by Matlab Compiler, I would like to know how to receive the results returned by the function after all calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 3 methods:

1. Save the results to a file.
2. [Print](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) the results to the terminal, either to stdout or to stderr, using `fprintf(1, ...)` or `fprintf(2, ...)`.
3. [Return an exit code](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exit.html) with `exit(code)`. This might work if you just want to return an integer.

Solution 2 and 3 might only work on linux. [This website](https://beagle.whoi.edu/redmine/projects/ibt/wiki/Calling_Matlab_from_the_Linux_command-line) has some more info about passing data into and out of the command line. I am not sure if this also works for compiled code, I do not have the Matlab compiler. It depends a bit on the type of data that you want to return. For anything more complex than a simple number, solution 1 is probably the best way.