# MATLAB - how to pass argument with command line and run the script

Tags: matlab

I Have a matlab script dbEval.m:

```
function dbEval()

....function implementation
....
end


 dbEval();%call this function.
```

I run this script on the shell with

```
matlab dbEval.m
```

Now if I want to pass a argument thru command line execute.
How can I do it? and how do I retrieve the argument on my script and use it as argument of my dbEval function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a matlab program with arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981168/running-a-matlab-program-with-arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
matlab -r 'dbEval(argument1, ... ,argumentN)';
```

or

```
matlab -r 'try dbEval(argument1, ... ,argumentN); catch; end; quit'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
matlab -r -nodesktop -nojvm 'dbEval(arg1 arg2 ...)'
```